# Getting invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] error

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I'm trying to compare the first character of a string to see if it matches and if it does, I want to set the clipboard data. The string comes from the getclipboard function and set to const char* data and I have tried to set it to std::string but I get a different error from that.
Here is my Clipboard.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstring>

namespace Diall_ClipBoard_catch
{
    class ClipBoard
    {
    private:
        ::HANDLE dHDat;
        ::std::string tmpstringsign;
        bool isopen;
        char* dHbuffer;
        char* dHbuffertemp;
        char* dNtoken;
    public:
        ClipBoard(void)
        {
            this->dHbuffer = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->dHbuffertemp = const_cast <char*>("");
            this->tmpstringsign = "dnb_4554_2102";
            this->isopen = false;
        };
        ~ClipBoard(void)
        {

        }
        char* GetData(void)
        {
            this->Start();
            if (this->isopen)
            {
                this->dHDat = ::GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);

                if (this->dHDat)
                {
                    this->dHbuffer = (char*)::GlobalLock(this->dHDat);

                    if (::std::strcmp(this->dHbuffertemp, this->dHbuffer) != 0 && this->dHbuffer != "" && this->dHbuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        this->dHbuffertemp = this->dHbuffer;
                        //::std::cout << this->dHbuffer << "\n";
                        return this->dHbuffer;
                    }

                    ::GlobalUnlock(this->dHDat);
                }
                CloseClipboard();
                this->isopen = FALSE;
                ::Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        void SetData(void)
        {
            const char* data = this->dHbuffer;
            const char* newstring = "Hello World";
            const size_t len = strlen(newstring) + 1;
            HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
            memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), newstring, len);
            GlobalUnlock(hMem);
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (strlen(data) == 8)
            {
                    if(data[0] == "1" || data[0] == "7")
                    {
                        EmptyClipboard();
                        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
                    }
            }
            CloseClipboard();
            this->isopen = TRUE;
        }
    private:
        void Start(void)
        {
            if (!OpenClipboard(NULL))
            {
                return;
            }
            this->isopen = true;
        }
    };
}
```

And here is my main.cpp

```
#include "Clipboard.h"

int main()
{
    ::Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard* clipboard = new Diall_ClipBoard_catch::ClipBoard();
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    EmptyClipboard();
    while (1)
    {
        temp1 = GetClipboardSequenceNumber();
        if (temp1!= temp2)
        {
            clipboard->SetData();
            std::cout << clipboard->GetData() << std::endl;
        }

        temp2 = temp1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing

```
data[0] = "1"
```

to

```
strcmp(data[0], 1) == 0
```

But I get a the same error.

The other problem I have is that the program only runs once in the sense that only the content of the clipboard is displayed and when I copy a different text, it doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Change

```
if(data[0] == "1" || data[0] == "7")
```

to

```
if(data[0] == '1' || data[0] == '7')
```

`data` is a `char*`, so dereferencing it with `data[0]` will give you a `char`. `"1"` is a string (`char*`) of length 1, which will result in an invalid comparison of `char` to `char*` (see the error).

What you probably want is the character `'1'`. We denote character literals in C++ with a single quote.

Comment: It works thank you for the help. I'm also getting an error with strlen(data) as it keeps returning 0.

Comment: Technically, `"1"` is a `const char[2]` that *decays* into a `const char*` pointer.